# Implementing Revit to Excel Exporter in Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am attempting to implement the Revit to Excel exporter discussed [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/create-spreadsheet-excel-client-translated-revit-files).  The button is working and passing urn and token to

```
ForgeXLS.downloadXLSX(urn, token, callback /*Optional*/);
```

I receive an error" "GET " 403 (forbidden)"
[image]

I am extending the Extensions Skeleton tutorial found [here](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/skeleton).

Is it possible that there is an issue with the scopes... if so can you guide me as to how to adjust the scope of the access token I am pulling?

Code for ForgeXLSX.downloadXLSX is:

```
downloadXLSX: function (urn, token, status) {
    var fileName = decodeURIComponent(atob(urn).replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')) + '.xlsx';
    if (fileName.indexOf('.rvt') == -1) {
      if (status) status(true, 'Not a Revit file, aborting.');
      return;
    }

    if (status) {
      status(false, 'Preparing ' + fileName);
      status(false, 'Reading project information....');
    }

    this.prepareTables(urn, token, function (tables) {
      if (status) status(false, 'Building XLSX file...');

      var wb = new Workbook();
      jQuery.each(tables, function (name, table) {
        if (name.indexOf('<')==-1) { // skip tables starting with <
          var ws = ForgeXLS.sheetFromTable(table);
          wb.SheetNames.push(name);
          wb.Sheets[name] = ws;
        }
      });

      var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType: 'xlsx', bookSST: true, type: 'binary'});
      saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], {type: "application/octet-stream"}), fileName);

      if (status) status(true, 'Downloading...');
    })
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Scope wise, you will need both **data:read bucket:read** to have sufficient access to model metadata:

[image]

Token with insufficient scope ends up with a 403:
[image]

Make sure your server sets scope up properly in the request body to fetch access tokens.

And your best bet to observe the URN and Token variables in the process of calling the Forge endpoints is [here at ForgeXLS.forgeGetRequest](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-extract.spreadsheet/blob/master/www/js/ForgeXLS.js#L29):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After digging around a bit (and some help from a friend) figured out that it was the scopes after all.  Adding 'data:read' scope to the public scope in the config.js file provided the needed access and the exporter now works.

```
 scopes: {
        // Required scopes for the server-side application
        internal: ['bucket:create', 'bucket:read', 'data:read', 'data:create', 'data:write'],
        // Required scope for the client-side viewer
        public: ['viewables:read', 'data:read']
    }
```